# Patch not working

Tags: 9

I am trying to apply patch to the core file but none solution work for me. even not able commit core file changes due composer restriction

composer.json

```
{
"name": "pantheon-upstreams/drupal-project",
"description": "Install Drupal 9 with Composer on Pantheon.",
"type": "project",
"license": "MIT",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    },
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "upstream-configuration"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "woocommerce/flexslider",
            "version": "2.7.2",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "2.7.2"
            }
        }
    },
    {
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "jsor/jcarousel",
    "version": "0.3.8",
    "type": "drupal-library",
    "dist": {
      "url": "https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/archive/0.3.8.zip",
      "type": "zip"
    }
  }
},
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "snake-345/jcarouselswipe",
    "version": "0.3.7",
    "type": "drupal-library",
    "dist": {
      "url": "https://github.com/snake-345/jcarouselswipe/archive/0.3.7.zip",
      "type": "zip"
    }
  }
}
],
"require": {
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "^3.3",
    "bower-asset/jquery-simple-color": "^1.2",
    "bower-asset/spectrum": "^1.8",
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
    "drupal/address": "^1.11",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.1",
    "drupal/aos-aos": "^1.0",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^5.2",
    "drupal/better_search": "^1.6",
    "drupal/better_social_sharing_buttons": "^4.0",
    "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^5.5",
    "drupal/captcha": "^1.4",
    "drupal/color_field": "^3.0",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.2",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.2",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "^2.1",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.4",
    "drupal/devel_entity_updates": "^3.0",
    "drupal/diff": "^1.0",
    "drupal/disable_link_rel": "^2.0",
    "drupal/embed": "^1.6",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.4",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.8",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.2",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.10",
    "drupal/extlink": "^1.6",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.2",
    "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.2",
    "drupal/file_mdm": "^2.4",
    "drupal/flexslider": "^2.0",
    "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.23",
    "drupal/fontawesome_menu_icons": "^1.9",
    "drupal/googlemap_block": "2.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/gtranslate": "^1.14",
    "drupal/hacked": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/header_and_footer_scripts": "^3.0",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^2.1",
    "drupal/hubspot": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/jcarousel": "^6.0@alpha",
    "drupal/jquery_carousel": "^1.0",
    "drupal/lazy": "^3.11",
    "drupal/link_attributes": "^1.11",
    "drupal/menu_block": "^1.8",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.2",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.21",
    "drupal/nofollowlist": "^2.0",
    "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0@beta",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.15",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
    "drupal/profile": "^1.4",
    "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.15",
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.8",
    "drupal/redis": "^1.5",
    "drupal/responsive_menu": "^4.4",
    "drupal/schema_metatag": "^2.3",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.28",
    "drupal/search_exclude_nid": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/sophron": "^1.2",
    "drupal/state_machine": "^1.6",
    "drupal/token": "^1.7",
    "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.1",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/views_autocomplete_filters": "^1.3",
    "drupal/views_autosubmit": "^1.4",
    "drupal/views_blogspot_archive": "^1.4",
    "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.5",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.1",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.8",
    "drupal/we_megamenu": "^1.13",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
    "drupal/webform_spam_words": "^2.0",
    "drupal/youtube": "^2.0",
    "drush/drush": "^10",
    "jsor/jcarousel": "^0.3.8",
    "npm-asset/jquery": "^2.2",
    "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
    "pantheon-systems/drupal-integrations": "^9",
    "pantheon-upstreams/upstream-configuration": "self.version",
    "snake-345/jcarouselswipe": "^0.3.7",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0",
    "woocommerce/flexslider": "~2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "drupal/core-dev": "^9.2"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "./web"
        },
        "allowed-packages": [
            "pantheon-systems/drupal-integrations"
        ],
        "file-mapping": {
            "[project-root]/.editorconfig": false,
            "[project-root]/pantheon.upstream.yml": false,
            "[project-root]/.gitattributes": false
        }
    },
    "installer-types": [
       "npm-asset",
       "bower-asset"
    ],
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:bower-asset",
            "type:npm-asset",
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ],
        "web/private/scripts/quicksilver/{$name}/": [
            "type:quicksilver-script"
        ]
    },
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patchLevel": {
        "drupal/core": "-p2"
    },
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "web/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
        ]
    }
},
"enable-patching": true,
"composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
"patches": {
     "drupal/core": {
        "Public files directory Not fully protected": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-03-04/3117665-non_apache_servers_4.patch",
        "Illegal offset type in isset or empty core": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-01-25/taxonomies-view-filter-core-fixes.patch",
        "view filter working core": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-01-25/date-view-filter-core_0.patch"                       
      }
     },
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.4"
    },
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true
    }
}
}
```

.gitignore

```
# This file contains .gitignore rules that are often used with Drupal projects.
# Because .gitignore is specific to your site and its deployment processes, you
# may need to uncomment, add, or remove rules.

# Pantheon commits a settings.php for environment-specific settings.
# Place local settings in settings.local.php
/web/sites/*/settings.local.php
/web/sites/*/services*.yml
!/web/sites/*/services.pantheon.*.yml
!/web/sites/*/services.yml

# Ignore paths that contain user-generated content.
/web/sites/*/files
/web/sites/*/private

# Ignore SimpleTest multi-site environment.
/web/sites/simpletest


# Ignore custom modules managed by Composer.
#
# When a development team creates one or more custom modules that
# are intended for use on more than one site, the typical strategy
# is to register them in Packagist and give them the type
# `drupal-custom-module` instead of `drupal-module`. This will cause
# Composer to install them to the directory `modules/custom`.
# This will cause a build error on Pantheon unless this location
# is .gitignore'd as shown below.
#
# An alternate strategy for custom modules is to commit them
# directly to the repository of the site where they are used. This
# is commonly done with modules that are specific to just one site.
# 
# Sites that have both Composer-managed custom modules and custom
# modules that are committed directly to the repository may ignore
# the `modules/custom` directory with the first rule shown below,
# and then allow the locations to be committed on a case-by-case
# basis by re-adding paths using `!` rules. A path that begins with
# a `!` will allow a previously-ignored path to be added to the
# repository. Note, however, that a path cannot be re-added if any
# of its parent directories are excluded. This is why we use the
# rule `/modules/custom/*` instead of `/modules/custom`. Alternately,
 # you might instead commit Git-tracked custom modules to some other
# path, such as /web/modules/<site-namespace>.
#
 # Sites that do not have any Composer-managed custom modules do
# not need to use any of the `modules/custom` rules below.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#/web/modules/custom/*
#!/web/modules/custom/module_in_repo


# Ignore directories generated by Composer
#
# See the "installer-paths" section in the top-level composer.json
# file.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
/drush/Commands/contrib/
!/web/core/modules/web/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/Date.php
!/web/core/modules/taxonomy/src/Plugin/views/filter/TaxonomyIndexTid.php
/web/core/
/web/modules/contrib/
/web/themes/contrib/
/web/profiles/contrib/
 /web/libraries/
/web/private/scripts/quicksilver
/web/themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/css/components/forum.css
/web/themes/contrib/bootstrap_barrio/css/components/image-widget.css
!/web/libraries/flexslider
!/web/core/modules/web/views/src/Plugin/views/filter/Date.php
!/web/core/modules/taxonomy/src/Plugin/views/filter/TaxonomyIndexTid.php


# Generally you should only ignore the root vendor directory. It's important
# that core/assets/vendor and any other vendor directories within contrib or
# custom module, theme, etc., are not ignored unless you purposely do so.
/vendor/

# Ignore other scaffold files
#
# Ignore all files placed directly at the project root. Rely on
# .gitignore files placed by drupal/core-composer-scaffold to avoid
# build errors that arise if non-ignored files are scaffolded.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
/.editorconfig
/.gitattributes

# The pantheon-systems/drupal-integrations project places a
# .drush-lock-update file at the project root.
/.drush-lock-update

# The drupal/core-composer-scaffold component will write .gitignore
# files to other locations where it scaffolds files that are not
# already ignored. We must also ignore these generated files.
/web/**/.gitignore


# Other common rules
# ------------------
# Ignore files generated by PhpStorm
#/.idea/

# Ignore .env files as they are personal
#/.env
```

Answer (score 3):

`patches` needs to be placed inside the `extra` section (on the same level as `patchLevel`, `installer-types`, etc.), not on the root level.

```
{
    "name": "pantheon-upstreams/drupal-project",
    ...(trimmed)...
    "extra": {
         ...(trimmed)...
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/core": {
                "Public files directory Not fully protected": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-03-04/3117665-non_apache_servers_4.patch",
                "Illegal offset type in isset or empty core": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-01-25/taxonomies-view-filter-core-fixes.patch",
                "view filter working core": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-01-25/date-view-filter-core_0.patch"                       
            }
        }
    }
}
```